# Constructing objects from a one-to-many relationships

Tags: database, graph, entity-relationship, nodes, data-modeling

### Context

I am designing a data model for a node based system used to perform tasks. The system includes node, plug and edge objects.

- A node is an object which performs an action. You can think of nodes as being like a program or executable. The functionality of the node may be altered via data passed through from other nodes.
- Data is passed from one node to another via a connection. A connection between two nodes is called an edge.
- Nodes are connected using plugs. Each node has a list of plugs which determine the input and output for the node. You can think of plugs as being like the arguments to a program or executable.

The relationship between nodes and plugs is a one-to-many relationship. So a node can have many plugs but a plug can only have one node. In this case I will store a reference to the node on each plug. Edges are really just an association between two plugs. Below is an example of how I imagine the data is stored:

The node table:

```
|-------------|-----|-------|
| PRIMARY_KEY | ID  | TYPE  |
|-------------|-----|-------|
| NODE.1      | 1   | NODE  |  
|-------------|-----|-------|
| NODE.2      | 2   | NODE  |  
|-------------|-----|-------|
```

The plug table:

```
|-------------|-----|-------|---------|
| PRIMARY_KEY | ID  | TYPE  | NODE    |
|-------------|-----|-------|---------|
| PLUG.1      | 1   | PLUG  | NODE.1  |  
|-------------|-----|-------|---------|
| PLUG.2      | 2   | PLUG  | NODE.2  |  
|-------------|-----|-------|---------|
| PLUG.3      | 3   | PLUG  | NODE.2  |  
|-------------|-----|-------|---------|
```

The edge table:

```
|-------------|-----|-------|----------|----------|
| PRIMARY_KEY | ID  | TYPE  | SRC_PLUG | DST_PLUG |
|-------------|-----|-------|----------|----------|
| EDGE.1      | 1   | EDGE  | PLUG.1   | PLUG.2   |
|-------------|-----|-------|----------|----------|
| EDGE.2      | 1   | EDGE  | PLUG.1   | PLUG.3   |
|-------------|-----|-------|----------|----------|
```

### Question

Assuming this is not completely wrong, my question is about how I would construct a node object from the data. It seems to me that a node is useless without the plugs which are associated to it. This suggests we must find all the plugs associated to the node at the time we create the node. Where and how is this information usually stored? In other words, how does the process used to create the node know to do the query for associated plugs?

All suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: In your example data, the same edge (EDGE.1) links two pairs of plugs. Was this intentional? Also are these edges directed?

Comment: Thanks! I have fixed the edge table now. There are two edges between two nodes but the edges are connecting different plugs. Also, the edges are directed - data is passed from the source plug to the destination plug. I have been doing some investigation and seems like I need to look into Object Relational Mapping (ORM). Know of any good resources/references? I am particularly interested in how this relates to physical data models.

Comment: ORM choice depends upon the programming language. It's a good thing to use ORMs. However, if this is an isolated piece of work which is limited in scope, then the overhead of an ORM might be too much. In that case, just writing your own code might be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like plugs are children of nodes and cannot exist until the node is created, unless the Node property of Plug can be null.  In that case you could pass one or more edges to the Node creator, and the node plugs would be the distinct set of destination plugs from them.

Having said that, it seems backwards in your example to create the plugs first, then the edges, then the nodes.  I would think the object which performs the action (node) would be created first and dictate the destination plugs it requires.  Edges would be defined last and would be more mutable over the lifetime of the application as different connections are created.  It feels more natural to define and create a node and its associated plugs together.

I'm not sure I understand the ID column of the Edge table or its relationship to PRIMARY_KEY or ID of another object.